# You cannot specify a unique constraint on a hashed index in MongoDB Shard cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

This might be a basic question on MongoDB, I'm having some issue in my MongoDB shard cluster because I do see duplicate entries in my cluster for some documents. As per my Mongod configuration, I have sharded with "Hashed shard" key.

```
shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
```

As per MongoDB documents, uniqueness can be forced only in ranged sharding, and does the Hash shard is not unique ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#unique-indexes reads:

> You cannot specify a unique constraint on a hashed index.

And gives some recommendations for such cases:

> MongoDB expects applications to enforce the uniqueness of the _id values across the shards.

Comment: as you mentioned, if we use hash sharding, we need to handle it with application side right ?

Comment: Using "hashed" shard key, would it tend to duplicate entries ?